# How do I print the board in full on one page?

Tags: trello, printing

Seems to print one column and lots of pages. How can we print the "board" like it is well like a white board?

Print screen does not work and is not ideal.

Comment: Does it print each list on a separate page when using the "Board options" - Print option?

Comment: Why does your Print Screen not work? Try and use a tool like Greenshot which enhances your print screen